# How to place ICs for handsoldering?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, soldering

I created a first version (by far finished) of a PCB, see below. The size of the PCB is 18x10 cm (about 7x4 inch). Most of the ICs are SOIC16 ICs with 1.27 mm pitch.

[image]

Because it would be nice to make it smaller, and fit in about 10x9 cm (4x4"), I used MS-Paint to fastly see if it would be possible to fit and I think it is possible. See below. Sorry for the non-professional look, but it's just to see if it would fit.

However, since I need to handsolder everything, I have some doubts about the distance between the ICs. My soldering technique is not that good (meaning I can solder 0805 but not so good 0603 to give some slight idea).

[image]

I am wondering if it would be easier to keep e.g. the 10 ICs at the right side like they are now, or to rotate them all 90 degrees , to form 2 lanes of horizontally placed ICs; I can imagine that I have more space to leave the soldering iron. I made a small example below with 5 ICs (except they just shouldn't touch each other).

[image]

(Also, I am intending to put all bypass capacitors on the bottom side (2 board layer), and I used handsoldering padsizes for all capacitors and resistors. If there are other techniques to make soldering easier, I'm interested too).

Comment: Looks like plenty of room either way to me. You're drag soldering, right? I will say that having them in in one long row will make it difficult to pry up pins if you need to remove an IC.

Comment: @DKNguyen although I took an electronics course where it was not advised to use drag soldering, I tried it once before and it seemed to work out easily.

Comment: I never drag solder, and I don't see a problem soldering either of those layouts by hand.

Comment: They can also be easily removed without prying up pins.  It takes a slightly longer tip on the iron, but there's no magic to doing it.

Comment: [Solder SMD IC.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/howtosolder-13soldersmdic)  [Remove SMD IC.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/howtosolder-14removesmdic)

Comment: If you're having trouble soldering, get yourself a stereo microscope and a tweezer set. It makes 0603's and even smaller fairly easy. Also make sure you've got an iron with temperature control (not just a 0-10 knob), and that your solder is good quality, with a flux core.

Comment: The second "layout" you posted is more than enough room to solder by hand. Special layouts for hand soldering are rarely required, unless you have tall parts on all sides of something that will physically get in the way of the iron.

Comment: @JRE Thanks for your comments, I will check the video.

Comment: @Draw I have a microscope(although I fairly cheap one, but it's stereoscopic) and a fairly reasonable soldering iron. I haven't tried it yet for soldering, but I will do first a 'test PCB'.

Comment: @Drew Ok good to know, thanks for that insight.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers:  No videos in the links I posted.  Explanations and photos.  Check the earlier parts of the series (linked in the Table of Contents) for hints on setting up your workplace, getting a vision aid if needed, and how to handle a soldering iron in general.

Comment: @JRE I will thanks ... I'm at work (well working from home; covid), so I didn't check the link yet, I will do this evening or tomorrow.

Comment: I'm sort of a video Luddite.  Video is for cats and movies, technical stuff requires written explanations.

Comment: @JRE Both have their benefits.. A video (or picture) says more than 1000 words, however, a video is mostly not the best way to find something specific or easily find back some information, while a text/document can be searched.

Comment: @JRE Those are indeed very good articles ... I read the first one (to solder) in detail and will try it out soon, for removing ICs I have no plans to do for the short term.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers:  Thank you for the compliment.  I've been working on that series for a couple of months now.  The subject kept coming up here, so I decided I'd write it all up and just point people at it instead of trying to answer things piece-meal every time some one runs into problems.